# How to order a Criteria (Hibernate) by an external query?

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-criteria

Let's say I have

```
 List cats = sess.createCriteria(Cat.class)
.add( Restrictions.like("name", "F%")
.addOrder( Order.asc("name") )
.list();
```

Lets presume the cat class has 2 more properties, `livesUsed` and `livesTotal`.

Is it possible to order ascending the criteria by a query that computes the difference between `livesTotal` and `livesUsed` without adding a new column to the db_cats with `livesDifference` ?

How do I implement that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Neither the group by clause nor the order by clause can contain
>   arithmetic expressions.

Taken from Hibernate documentation : http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html#queryhql-grouping